# 'catkin build' builds one more package than expected

Tags: catkin, ros-noetic, catkin-workspace

When I build my workspace using 'catkin build', in ros noetic, it returns to me 'All 3 packages are succeded', knowing that I only have 2 packages in my src folder. Is this normal? and will it cause problems as I move on with the project?

Comment: If possible, please [edit] and update your question with your `src` directory contents, as requested in Chris's answer. Thanks.

Comment: You seem to have two accounts: [1](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/users/39994/samy) and [2](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/users/40012/samy). You can merge the accounts, please see [I accidentally created two accounts; how do I merge them?](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts)

Answer (score 2):

generally it should not be a problem, if the build is successful. To properly answer your question it would be interesting to know what your `src` directory looks like. It sounds like one of your packages is a "metapackage". These can contain multiple packages.
Your `catkin build` command should also list the package names that are to be build.

Comment: Thank you guys, for some reason, the problem seems to be solved by itself. I just kept working and at one point I had "All 2 packages are succeded", I don't know how but everything looks good at the moment. Anyway, thanks again for your answers.